# How do I stop "badness" if I want a new line within my table?

Tags: tables

[image: error message]I want to make a table with new lines for each sentence. Using `\\` will not work because that is reserved for new table rows. Instead, I use `\newline` or `\linebreak` which does the job perfectly, except the console has error message `Underfull \hbox (badness 8703) in paragraph...` . Is this "bad"? It is getting the job done.

Here is an example from my table

```
 \subsection{Social Change}
\underline{Major Social Developments under Mao} 
\begin{table}[H]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.4cm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\hskip-2.7cm\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}p{8.1cm} p{7cm}}
\hline

`Education & Learning should come from experience \linebreak Economic development could be stimulated by large numbers of skilled specialists and improving mass literacy \linebreak Young people encouraged to learn from the peasants   
& Rejected traditional education for elitism, old-fashioned teaching methods and reliance on books\newline Opposed Western influence - cultural imperialism \\
```

Comment: you could use `\newline`  or simply use `\raggedright` and let the linebreaking be automatic.  (`\newline` will leave the line short and make no warnings) `\linebreak` will keep the text justified so stretch the white space and give warnings.

Comment: it still has an error message. Ive pasted that in my post

Comment: text in narrow columns is usually better set ragged but you can obviously fix all those warnings if you do all the line breaking by hand with `\newline` but if you set the text `\raggedright` hand line breaks probably are not needed at all

Comment: As you hav eprovided no example document just a fragment it's not so easy to post a tested answer.

Comment: in your text you say you want a newline for each sentence, but in your code fragment you have used `\linebreak` (not `\newline`) and used it mid-sentence (not at the end of a sentence) so I do not understand the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear what output you want, but this runs with no warnings

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,array}

\begin{document}

 \subsection{Social Change}
\underline{Major Social Developments under Mao}% underline, really?
 
\begin{table}[htp]%[H]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.4cm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\hspace*{-4cm}\begin{tabular}{
p{2.5cm}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{8.1cm}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{7cm}}
\hline

 Education & Learning should come from experience Economic development could be stimulated by large numbers of skilled specialists and improving mass literacy  Young people encouraged to learn from the peasants   
 & Rejected traditional education for elitism, old-fashioned teaching methods and reliance on books
Opposed Western influence --- cultural imperialism
\end{tabular}\hspace*{-4cm}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a left-justified `\Longunderstack` to manually set the line breaks.  I also show how the baselineskip between rows can be set via `\setstackgap{L}{<length>}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\begin{document}
 \subsection{Social Change}
\underline{Major Social Developments under Mao} 
\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.4cm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\hskip-2.7cm\begin{tabular}{p{2.1cm}p{8.1cm} p{7.4cm}}
\hline
Education & \Longunderstack[l]{
  Learning should come from experience \\
  Economic development could be stimulated\\
   by large numbers of skilled specialists \\
  and improving mass literacy \\
Young people encouraged to learn from the\\
   peasants }
& \setstackgap{L}{1.3\normalbaselineskip}
\Longunderstack[l]{
  Rejected traditional education for elitism, old-\\
  fashioned teaching methods and reliance on books\\
 Opposed Western influence---cultural imperialism }
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]